# jquery-Ajax call on tornado handlers waits for pervious ajax call to return

Tags: jquery, tornado

I recently started testing TornadoWeb for a home-project, which uses jquery getJSON function to call my tornado handlers. And found something strange, which i seek an explanation for.

I fire an ajax request for *Handler1* on tornado, and in some cases request for *Handler2* is initiated before *Handler1* returns. It appears from development-server logs, and firebug console-debugging, that *Handler2* request waits for *Handler1* request to finish, and then return. So basically, XHR call is waiting for earlier XHRs. They are supposed to be asynchronous/non-blocking right?? Or am i missing something.

You can check the test-case environment called *testtornado* at *http://github.com/harshh/Harsh-Projects/* with main.py as server triggering file.

I would appreciate help from anyone who can throw some light on this.

Comment: Would you be able to share a little more information about the call you are trying to make in jquery. If you could, could you post an example of the javascript that you are trying to execute.

Comment: The whole code is in github repository stated in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get better explanations here. Although some better insights can be found [Tornado group discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/f0585fedfd0bf353/8ea0ac2aa3c8817b). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your test.js file, get_handler1 and get_handler2 are entirely independent of each other.  However, your browser or proxy (if you're using one) may be enforcing a one request per domain limit which would cause your XHR requests to appear to be synchronous.  Popular HTTP debugging proxies such as Fiddler can enforce such limits -- browsers also tend to have settings which you can modify to ensure your browser will issue more than one request per domain concurrently.